# jquery-mobile and stopping an ajax request in my rails app

Tags: jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using JQuery mobile to build my rails app (ruby 2, rails 4).

Users can log in with Facebook:

```
<%= link_to "Log in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: "custom-btn" %>
```

It works fine when I disable JQuery mobile - when I comment out the line in my application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" %>
```

But with jquery mobile being used I get the error, when I click the 'Log in with FB' button: 'error loading page'.

I think this is because a callback is being initiated to the FB site, which Jquery Mobile doesn't like, as ajax is used by default, and it wants everything to stay within my domain. So I'm trying to disable ajax for this request. In the jquery mobile support docs it says this can be done with:

```
data-ajax="false"
```

But what is the syntax for my button? I've tried lots of different things like:

```
<%= link_to "Log in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), class: "custom-btn", data-ajax: "false" %>
```

but it just gives me errors. Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
"data-ajax" => "false"
```

as in:

```
<%= link_to "Log in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook), "data-ajax" => "false", class: "custom-btn" %>
```

Although I did think `=>` was deprecated in Rails 4.